# What is the meaning of load of a line?

Tags: load, line

in Powerworld there is a function called ''line flow pie'' which indicate the percentage of load of the line. But what is it? I think that it is the ratio between the current on the line and its nominal value times 100. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The line flow pie charts are used to indicate the percentage MVA, MW, or Mvar loading of a transmission line or a transformer. The degree to which the pie chart is filled shows how close the device is to its limit (provided the device has a nonzero limit). A line flow pie chart becomes completely filled when the device's flow meets or exceeds 100% of its rating.

So rather than current, it is indicating power (Real, reactive, or true).

https://www.powerworld.com/WebHelp/Content/MainDocumentation_HTML/Line_Flow_Pie_Charts_on_Onelines.htm

Comment: but how can we calculate the power limit that a line could deliver?

Comment: That is a wholly separate question, I would suggest posting it as such or looking for similar questions that already exist, such as: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351371/what-are-important-metrics-of-high-voltage-power-lines/351514#351514
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423390/how-much-power-can-transit-through-a-power-line-linking-generation-and-load

Comment: thank you very much!